# Search Custom Post with meta_value NULL

Tags: wp-query

I need to get only the custom posts which have `meta_key` `landing_exported` as `meta_value` `NULL`.

I know that exists at least 2 custom posts in my database, but my code print "nothing found".

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'     => LANDING__CUSTOM_POST,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'landing_exported',
                    'value' => false,
                    'type' => 'BOOLEAN'
                )
            )
        );

        // query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

           // do funny things

        } else {

           echo 'nothing found';

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I depends if you're looking for an empty value:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => LANDING__CUSTOM_POST,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'landing_exported',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

which searches for value like: `meta_value = ''`

or if you are looking for actually a `NULL` value which is more difficult (or I couldn't find an easier solution):

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_modify_the_posts_where' );
function lets_modify_the_posts_where( $clause = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $clause .= " AND " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta.meta_value IS NULL"
    return $clause;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'  => LANDING__CUSTOM_POST,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'landing_exported',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

remove_filter('posts_where', 'my_modify_the_posts_where');
```

which searches for value like: `meta_value IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where are you getting that `BOOLEAN` type from. I don’t think it is a type supported by `WP_Query`.

Since meta values are always *stored* as text anyway, it is hard to guess what precisely do you mean by the `NULL` value.

You should examine what is the actual value in database, resulting from your code, and query accordingly. It might be something like `'NULL'` string, or it might be empty string, or it might be unset altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'posts_where',      'cb2_posts_where_allow_NULL_meta_query' );
function cb2_posts_where_allow_NULL_meta_query( $where ) {
    return preg_replace(
        "/CAST\(([a-z0-9_]+)\.([a-z0-9_]+) AS SIGNED\)\s*IN\s*\(([^)]*)'NULL'/mi",
        'CAST(\1.\2 AS SIGNED) IN(\3NULL',
        $where
    );
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?